# how to return json object from Azure Runbook to Power Automate

Tags: power-automate, azure-runbook

I have a PowerShell runbook in Azure and I'm calling it from PowerAutomate. I would like to return a json object for further processing. I tried 3 versions:

```
$credential = Get-AutomationPSCredential -Name 'messages'
$connection = connect-microsoftteams -credential $credential
$q = Get-CsCallQueue | convertto-json
write-output $q
```

or

```
$q = Get-CsCallQueue
return $q
```

or this:

```
$q = Get-CsCallQueue | convertto-json
return $q
```

In all 3 cases the response body is string like:

> "body": "{\r\n    "DisplayDistributionLists":
> "532bc784-f6c4-499c-aaad-47478aa2d890",\r\n    "DisplayUsers":
> {\r\n                     },\r\n    "DisplayAgents":
> "46986d86-6128-441b-a042-8caceecaa324...

When I look at the job, I can see that it is returning the Json array. What can I do to make Flow recognise that a json object is returned, not a string?

Answer (score 0):

I assume your flow's trigger is 'When an HTTP request is received', do you submit your header with Content-type: application/json?
Next to that, your JSON schema has to be filled in, in the trigger's schema. Is this done correctly?

Comment: No. The way around. The flow triggers the runbook that returns value to the flow.

Comment: Parse JSON action where you process the output so PowerAutomate knows its JSON

Comment: I know. The problem is not parsing a valid json, but when it arrives inside the flow, it is a string, with all sort of escape characters.

Comment: Have you generated your schema by an example via the wizard?
The tabs and newline shouldn't matter, I guess your schema is invalid.